# jQuery slider drawing different heights?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, slidetoggle

I don't know how to best explain this, but I'm attempting to use a script I found online that partially hides the content of a div, and then expands when the "Read More" button is clicked.

Here is the link: http://elderoptions.staging.wpengine.com/

The problem is that sometimes it is cutting off the content at the very bottom of the screen. It works best in Firefox.

It seems like the script is drawing different heights.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another note: I don't know why this makes any sense, but if I'm on the page and the slider isn't working, and then I press the "Home" link - it seems to then load properly every time. I just tested that about 15 times and it worked.

I have no idea why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

The site mentioned is outdated and uses depreciated html and jquery code. Personally, I would **NOT** using their script.

Instead I have provided you with a working example of something similar. Feel free to use this. Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/mTN2P/95/

Comment: That looks great! Is there a simple way to apply the smooth opening and closing animation? Thanks!

Comment: This should be what you are looking for. If not, let me know.  http://jsfiddle.net/mTN2P/140/